# Fetch data from API only once and filter on client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have data on a flask backend that I would like to fetch and display on my react frontend. By using hooks data will be fetched every time the page is requested. What I would like to do is to fetch data only once at the beginning (if it is not already fetched) and then I can adapt it to each frontend page without having to fetch the data every time a filter on my page changes.

Is there a standard way to solve this problem? Do I have to use redux to persist state on the frontend or is there an easier way?

Comment: What do you call a "page"? An HTTP page or a React page (i.e. a component rendered on a specific path via react-router)? You can't persist data across HTTP pages, unless you store the results in LocalStorage.

Comment: @GG. A component rendered via react-router

Comment: Oh, then you can fetch the data once at the top level (like App.jsx), pass it down to every page that needs the data via its props, and filter the data in the pages.

Comment: But then i have to modify every component to accept data props. Redux might be better in this case.

Comment: Yep exactly. It's fine to start but once you manage a lot of different data, Redux helps a lot.

Comment: Just use useEffect, and put an empty array as a dependency. Call API in useEffect, So, it will run only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react context to achieve this:

```
// context.tsx
type ContextType = {
  prop1: any
  prop2: any
}

// create context
const MyContext = createContext( {} as ContextType )

// create provider
export const ContextProvider = ( {
  children
} ) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(....)
  const otherProp = 'abc123'

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setData(() => await handleGetDataOnFirstLoad())
    })()
  }, [])

  const exported = useMemo<ContextType>( () => ( {
    prop1: data.prop1,
    prop2: data.prop2,
    // or just
    data,
    otherProp
  } ), [ 
    // add here variables that will 
    // make react rerender this component
    data
  ] )

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={ exported }
    >
      { children }
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

/**
 * Creates a custom hook
 *
 * @return {ContextType} context
 */
export function useMyContext(): ContextType {
  const context = useContext( TimeoutContext )
  if ( !context ) throw new Error( 'Timeout context invalid' )
  return context
}

// your_root_component.txs
import { ContextProvider } from 'path/to/file'

....

return (
  <ContextProvider>
    ... components that will have access to data of this context
  </ContextProvider>
)


// any_component.tsx
import { useMyContext } from 'path/to/file'

function MyComponent() {
  const {prop1, prop2} = useMyContext()

  .....
}
```